# Is there a way to add new aws regions to Ansible ec2 module, which still uses old boto?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, boto3, boto

Old boto is used in ansible aws ec2 module, which is outdated. last commit 2018y. How do u provision instances in new regions?

my current version of ansible 2.9.6, but in 2.10 & 2.11 changelog there are nothing about chenge to boto3

region list in boto:
[eu-west-1, eu-west-2, cn-north-1, us-east-2, us-gov-west-1, ca-central-1, ap-southeast-2, us-west-2, ap-southeast-1, us-east-1, sa-east-1, us-west-1, ap-northeast-2, eu-central-1, ap-south-1, ap-northeast-1]

region list using boto3:
['af-south-1', 'ap-east-1', 'ap-northeast-1', 'ap-northeast-2', 'ap-south-1', 'ap-southeast-1', 'ap-southeast-2', 'ca-central-1', 'eu-central-1', 'eu-north-1', 'eu-south-1', 'eu-west-1', 'eu-west-2', 'eu-west-3', 'me-south-1', 'sa-east-1', 'us-east-1', 'us-east-2', 'us-west-1', 'us-west-2']

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quote from https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/ec2_module.html

> Note: This module uses the older boto Python module to interact with the EC2 API. amazon.aws.ec2 will still receive bug fixes, but no new features. Consider using the [amazon.aws.ec2_instance](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/aws/ec2_instance_module.html) module instead.

Comment: thx, it did the trick with this community version, which is included in default installation.
Cant find instance count though.